Hide the fact of using android emulation
I have the following code that identifies whether an android device is emulated, I need to use qemu to try to cheat this code, I found several lines in it related to the detection of QEMU specifically, but I'm not sure about the method itself and using QEMU to emulate ARM android, maybe you can use x86 android to cheat this code?
public class EmuDetector {

    static class Property {
        public String name;
        public String seek_value;

        public Property(String name, String seek_value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.seek_value = seek_value;
        }
    }

    public interface OnEmulatorDetectorListener {
        void onResult(boolean isEmulator);
    }

    private enum EmulatorTypes {
        GENY, ANDY, NOX, BLUE, PIPES, X86
    }

    private static final String[] PHONE_NUMBERS = {
            "15555215554", "15555215556", "15555215558", "15555215560", "15555215562", "15555215564",
            "15555215566", "15555215568", "15555215570", "15555215572", "15555215574", "15555215576",
            "15555215578", "15555215580", "15555215582", "15555215584"
    };

    private static final String[] DEVICE_IDS = {
            "000000000000000",
            "e21833235b6eef10",
            "012345678912345"
    };

    private static final String[] IMSI_IDS = {
            "310260000000000"
    };

    private static final String[] GENY_FILES = {
            "/dev/socket/genyd",
            "/dev/socket/baseband_genyd"
    };

    private static final String[] QEMU_DRIVERS = {"goldfish"};

    private static final String[] PIPES = {
            "/dev/socket/qemud",
            "/dev/qemu_pipe"
    };

    private static final String[] X86_FILES = {
            "ueventd.android_x86.rc",
            "x86.prop",
            "ueventd.ttVM_x86.rc",
            "init.ttVM_x86.rc",
            "fstab.ttVM_x86",
            "fstab.vbox86",
            "init.vbox86.rc",
            "ueventd.vbox86.rc"
    };

    private static final String[] ANDY_FILES = {
            "fstab.andy",
            "ueventd.andy.rc"
    };

    private static final String[] NOX_FILES = {
            "fstab.nox",
            "init.nox.rc",
            "ueventd.nox.rc",
            "/BigNoxGameHD",
            "/YSLauncher"
    };

    private static final String[] BLUE_FILES = {
            "/Android/data/com.bluestacks.home",
            "/Android/data/com.bluestacks.settings"
    };

    private static final Property[] PROPERTIES = {
            new Property("init.svc.qemud", null),
            new Property("init.svc.qemu-props", null),
            new Property("qemu.hw.mainkeys", null),
            new Property("qemu.sf.fake_camera", null),
            new Property("qemu.sf.lcd_density", null),
            new Property("ro.bootloader", "unknown"),
            new Property("ro.bootmode", "unknown"),
            new Property("ro.hardware", "goldfish"),
            new Property("ro.kernel.android.qemud", null),
            new Property("ro.kernel.qemu.gles", null),
            new Property("ro.kernel.qemu", "1"),
            new Property("ro.product.device", "generic"),
            new Property("ro.product.model", "sdk"),
            new Property("ro.product.name", "sdk"),
            new Property("ro.serialno", null)
    };

    private static final String IP = "10.0.2.15";

    private static final int MIN_PROPERTIES_THRESHOLD = 0x5;

    private final Context mContext;
    private boolean isTelephony = false;
    private boolean isCheckPackage = true;
    private List<String> mListPackageName = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean detected;
    private boolean detectResult;

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") //Since we use application context now this won't leak memory anymore. This is only to please Lint
    private static EmuDetector mEmulatorDetector;

    public static EmuDetector with(Context pContext) {
        if (pContext == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context must not be null.");
        }
        if (mEmulatorDetector == null) {
            mEmulatorDetector = new EmuDetector(pContext.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mEmulatorDetector;
    }

    private EmuDetector(Context pContext) {
        mContext = pContext;
        mListPackageName.add("com.google.android.launcher.layouts.genymotion");
        mListPackageName.add("com.bluestacks");
        mListPackageName.add("com.bignox.app");
        mListPackageName.add("com.vphone.launcher");
    }

    public boolean isCheckTelephony() {
        return isTelephony;
    }

    public boolean isCheckPackage() {
        return isCheckPackage;
    }

    public EmuDetector setCheckTelephony(boolean telephony) {
        this.isTelephony = telephony;
        return this;
    }

    public EmuDetector setCheckPackage(boolean chkPackage) {
        this.isCheckPackage = chkPackage;
        return this;
    }

    public EmuDetector addPackageName(String pPackageName) {
        this.mListPackageName.add(pPackageName);
        return this;
    }

    public EmuDetector addPackageName(List<String> pListPackageName) {
        this.mListPackageName.addAll(pListPackageName);
        return this;
    }

    public boolean detect() {
        if (detected) {
            return detectResult;
        }
        try {
            detected = true;
            if (!detectResult) {
                detectResult = checkBasic();
            }
            if (!detectResult) {
                detectResult = checkAdvanced();
            }
            if (!detectResult) {
                detectResult = checkPackageName();
            }
            if (!detectResult) {
                detectResult = EmuInputDevicesDetector.detect();
            }
            return detectResult;
        } catch (Exception ignore) {

        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkBasic() {
        boolean result =
                Build.BOARD.toLowerCase().contains("nox")
                        || Build.BOOTLOADER.toLowerCase().contains("nox")
                        || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
                        || Build.MODEL.toLowerCase().contains("google_sdk")
                        || Build.MODEL.toLowerCase().contains("droid4x")
                        || Build.MODEL.toLowerCase().contains("emulator")
                        || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
                        || Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase().contains("genymotion")
                        || Build.HARDWARE.toLowerCase().contains("goldfish")
                        || Build.HARDWARE.toLowerCase().contains("vbox86")
                        || Build.HARDWARE.toLowerCase().contains("android_x86")
                        || Build.HARDWARE.toLowerCase().contains("nox")
                        || Build.HARDWARE.toLowerCase().contains("ranchu")
                        || Build.PRODUCT.equals("sdk")
                        || Build.PRODUCT.equals("google_sdk")
                        || Build.PRODUCT.equals("sdk_x86")
                        || Build.PRODUCT.equals("vbox86p")
                        || Build.PRODUCT.toLowerCase().contains("nox")
                        || Build.SERIAL.toLowerCase().contains("nox");

        if (result) {
            return true;
        }
        result |= Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic");
        if (result) {
            return true;
        }
        result |= "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
        return result;
    }

    private boolean checkAdvanced() {
        return checkTelephony()
                || checkFiles(GENY_FILES, EmulatorTypes.GENY)
                || checkFiles(ANDY_FILES, EmulatorTypes.ANDY)
                || checkFiles(NOX_FILES, EmulatorTypes.NOX)
                || checkFiles(BLUE_FILES, EmulatorTypes.BLUE)
                || checkQEmuDrivers()
                || checkFiles(PIPES, EmulatorTypes.PIPES)
                || checkIp()
                || (checkQEmuProps() && checkFiles(X86_FILES, EmulatorTypes.X86));
    }

    private boolean checkPackageName() {
        if (!isCheckPackage || mListPackageName.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        final PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
        for (final String pkgName : mListPackageName) {
            final Intent tryIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName);
            if (tryIntent != null) {
                final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(tryIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                if (!resolveInfos.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkTelephony() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && this.isTelephony && isSupportTelePhony() && (checkPhoneNumber() || checkDeviceId() || checkImsi() || checkOperatorNameAndroid());
    }

    private boolean checkPhoneNumber() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        @SuppressLint("HardwareIds") String phoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();

        for (String number : PHONE_NUMBERS) {
            if (number.equalsIgnoreCase(phoneNumber)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkDeviceId() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        @SuppressLint("HardwareIds") String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

        for (String known_deviceId : DEVICE_IDS) {
            if (known_deviceId.equalsIgnoreCase(deviceId)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkImsi() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        @SuppressLint("HardwareIds") String imsi = telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();

        for (String known_imsi : IMSI_IDS) {
            if (known_imsi.equalsIgnoreCase(imsi)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkOperatorNameAndroid() {
        String operatorName = ((TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getNetworkOperatorName();
        return operatorName.equalsIgnoreCase("android");
    }

    private boolean checkQEmuDrivers() {
        for (File drivers_file : new File[]{new File("/proc/tty/drivers"), new File("/proc/cpuinfo")}) {
            if (drivers_file.exists() && drivers_file.canRead()) {
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                try {
                    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(drivers_file);
                    is.read(data);
                    is.close();
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

                String driver_data = new String(data);
                for (String known_qemu_driver : QEMU_DRIVERS) {
                    if (driver_data.contains(known_qemu_driver)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkFiles(String[] targets, EmulatorTypes type) { //TODO scoped storage
        for (String pipe : targets) {
            File qemu_file;
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if ((pipe.contains("/") && type == EmulatorTypes.NOX) || type == EmulatorTypes.BLUE) {
                    qemu_file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + pipe);
                } else {
                    qemu_file = new File(pipe);
                }
            } else {
                qemu_file = new File(pipe);
            }
            if (qemu_file.exists()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkQEmuProps() {
        int found_props = 0;

        for (Property property : PROPERTIES) {
            String property_value = getProp(mContext, property.name);
            if ((property.seek_value == null) && (property_value != null)) {
                found_props++;
            }
            if ((property.seek_value != null)
                    && (property_value.contains(property.seek_value))) {
                found_props++;
            }
        }

        return found_props >= MIN_PROPERTIES_THRESHOLD;
    }

    private boolean checkIp() {
        boolean ipDetected = false;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] args = {"/system/bin/netcfg"};
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
                builder.directory(new File("/system/bin/"));
                builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                Process process = builder.start();
                InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
                byte[] re = new byte[1024];
                while (in.read(re) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append(new String(re));
                }
                in.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // empty catch
            }

            String netData = stringBuilder.toString();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(netData)) {
                String[] array = netData.split("\n");

                for (String lan :
                        array) {
                    if ((lan.contains("wlan0") || lan.contains("tunl0") || lan.contains("eth0")) && lan.contains(IP)) {
                        ipDetected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return ipDetected;
    }

    private String getProp(Context context, String property) {
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = context.getClassLoader();
            Class<?> systemProperties = classLoader.loadClass("android.os.SystemProperties");

            Method get = systemProperties.getMethod("get", String.class);

            Object[] params = new Object[1];
            params[0] = property;

            return (String) get.invoke(systemProperties, params);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            // empty catch
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isSupportTelePhony() {
        PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
        return packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
    }
}


None of these tests are actually checking if its an emulator (which is kind of impossible to do, as the emulator actually runs an Android OS, from the point of view of an app on the phone there is no difference between the two).  What you're looking for is a certain setup.  The easiest thing to do would be to make an emulator run a custom version of AOSP and every one of your tests could be made to fail.

Also several of your tests, such as the IP test, could have false positives.  A real device on a Wifi network could easily be assigned that IP address, as it's a valid address on one of the 3 address spaces reserved for LANs.

It is nice of you posting all those emulator detection techniques, that makes it easier for other users to detect and bypass it using apktool or Frida.
